# How do I append an LI to an UL using jQuery forms.js

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have multiple forms on a page and i'm trying to use jQuery form.js to save each comment that is posted and then append the comment to the UL afterwards.  The save part of it is working fine. However, I am having trouble getting the comment to update the UL correctly.  See code below:

```
//My Form
<form method="post" action="includes/answer.php" id="respond">
<input name="key_id" id="key_id" type="hidden" value="'.$row['thekey'].'" />
<textarea name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
</form>

//The UL
<ul id="'.$row['thekey'].'" class="answer"></ul>

//The jQuery
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('form').ajaxForm({
        target: 'ul',
        success: function(data) {
            $('ul#' + data.id).prepend("<li style='display:none'>"+data.comment+"</li>").fadeIn('slow');
            $("ul#" + data.id +"li:first").fadeIn();
        }
    });
});

//Postback Code
    $message = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']));
    $id = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['key_id']));

    $sql_id = 'SELECT id FROM questions WHERE thekey = "'.$id.'"';
    $select_result = mysql_query($sql_id);

    if($select_result) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($select_result);
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO answers (answer, question_id) VALUES("'.$message.'", '.$row['id'].')';
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        if($result) {
            print json_encode(array("id" => $id, "comment" => $message));
        }
    }
```

This is currently outputting an array that looks something like {"id":"sadfasdf2","comment":"ds"} in place of the ul tags.  How can I get it to output the actual comment in a LI?

Comment: Can you provide some sample output or a link? I don't fully follow your last two phrases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$('ul#' + data.id).prepend("<li style='display:none'>"+data.comment+"</li>").fadeIn('slow');
```

to:

```
$('ul#' + data.id).prepend($("<li></li>").text(data.comment).hide()).fadeIn('slow');
```

A bit explanation:

`$("<li></li>")` is how you create a new element. Then you can `.text(content)` on that element to set the content (`.html(htmlcode)` also works). `.hide()` is the same as `style="display:none"`.

EDIT: owh and also, remove the `target: 'ul',` .. it's the config that tells ajaxForm to directly inject the response into the UL tag.

Comment: I gave it a try and it still appears to be outputting the array instead of actually adding the li to the list.

Comment: Nope, still something else is wrong...  I removed the target: 'ul', and it still saves correctly, but doesn't add the new comment to the list. hmmm....

Comment: then remove the `.hide()` part :)

Comment: or move the .fadeIn() into the preceding parentheses: `$('ul#' + data.id).prepend($("<li></li>").text(data.comment).hide().fadeIn('slow'));`

Comment: It's working! Thanks! Any idea how I would get it to put the LI at the very bottom instead of the top?

Comment: as in the title of your question, use `.append()` instead of `.prepend()` >___<

Comment: ahhh now it is perfect.  Thanks so much for your help!